# Convert Buffer to integer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get this buffer from my serial port:

```
<Buffer 04 02 08 dc>
```

The 2nd byte says how many bytes do I need to parse my from response data. So I need to parse these two bytes `08 dc`, and convert them to `long unsigned`.

How do I do it in JavaScript on a Node.js server?

Comment: Are they big- or little-endian? (i.e. do you want 0x08dc or 0xdc08?) What’s the highest possible number of bytes? (If long = 8 bytes, note that JavaScript can’t represent those precisely without a BigInt.)

Comment: Anyway, read around here: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readintbe_offset_bytelength

Comment: @Ry- thx for the answer, however I rly dont know if they are BE or LE, i've looking at the API before I post this :/, any Idea how to find this? It should be some specification?

Comment: Also using the nodejs API to convert these buffers, it gives me weird numbers, for example its not possible for that i'm reading an instante voltages of 2280 volts, when the maximum voltage in my country is 220v

Comment: There is no such thing as "long unsigned" in JavaScript. What are you gonna do with the integer? It might be better to keep them in the buffer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[buf.readInt32BE([offset]) and
buf.readInt32LE([offset])](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readint32be_offset) let you read a 32b int from 4-bytes starting at `offset`.

> Reads a signed 32-bit integer from buf at the specified offset with the specified endian format (`readInt32BE()` returns big endian, `readInt32LE()` returns little endian).
>
> Integers read from a `Buffer` are interpreted as two's complement signed values.

Comment: Thank you. I've read the docs, and everything you said was correct, I've just miss-understood the docs of my power meter.

Comment: @bmvr, I'm glad you've got it sorted.  There are variants that take a `byteLength` argument which might work with your "2nd byte says ..." requirement, though not for byteLengths > 6 because JavaScript uses floating point numbers with a 52b mantissa.